# Valores dos campos da activity são apagados após evento no DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho uma Activity que possui alguns campos de texto. Dois deles abrem um FragmentDialog quando clicados. Os dialogos exibem um lista com valores que são levados para a Activity via intent quando selecionados.
Quando isso acontece os campos que já foram preenchidos na Activity são apagados.

Creio que seja algum problema com o ciclo de vida da Activity, mas depois de horas pesquisando não consegui resolver esse problema.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Olá, Pedro. Seja bem-vindo. Precisamos ver o código pra ter uma ideia do que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de você usar um **FragmentDialog** use um **Dialog**. Provavelmente ele ta resetando a sua tela porque esta chamando uma nova **Activity**.

Usando o **Dialog** você pode chamar um layout criando em xml e dar um **findViewById** em todos as view dele. Você pode também mandar variáveis e objetos da sua **Activity** para o **Dialog** deixando eles estáticos ou final.
Para fechar o **Dialog** você tem que dar um **dismiss()** e ele retorna pra sua activity sem criar uma nova. Ai ta um exemple de como criar um **Dialog** com um layout de um botão.

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_que_vc_criou);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

            Button btnSair = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSair);

            btnSair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```